# How to implement vertically moving tabbs panel?

Tags: android, tabs

In google play, if you enter a screen that uses tabs, you can notice how you can scroll each tab but the panel that seen to contain the tabs also moves vertically to a certain extent. I can imagine that it accomplishes the movement of the tab panel with a TranslateAnimation and a layout animations. But what I can't understand is how it decouples the content of the tab from the tab panel.
[image]

Comment: You can try with this libarary https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the decoupling of the tabs and content question; I have implemented this before using 2 sets of tabs. One is in the content as a list header, the other is layered on top of the list in a containing FrameLayout so it's 'floating'.

Using scroll callbacks you can change the visibility of the floating tabs to suit your needs. Once the list header tabs moves off the screen make the floating tabs visible, once they move fully back onto the screen hide the floating tabs.

Just ensure that every time you show/hide tabs that you copy the values for horizontal scroll position and selected tab from the currently visible tabs to the ones that are about to become visible. works a treat.

Comment: What is the widget that you used for the header with the tab titles?

Comment: I used the sliding tabs official sample: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The best open-source project you can find for this [Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

[image]
[image]
[image]